# What question has had the most bounties on it?

Tags: support, bounties, statistics

Out of all the questions on SE, which has had the most bounties? I don't care about total amount of rep, just how many separate bounties there were.

Answer (score 7):

I dropped  the query from Nicael in my Multi-db query template and [this is the result](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/386643):

```
-- start create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      -- we have three sites that have borked DNS entries
      set @dbname = (case @dbname
      when 'StackExchange.Audio' then 'StackExchange.Avp'
      when 'StackExchange.Audio.Meta' then 'StackExchange.Avp.Meta'
      when 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta' then 'net.Mathoverflow.meta'
      else @dbname
      end)
      -- and one of those doesn't want to end with .com
      if @dbname <> 'net.Mathoverflow.meta' 
         set @dbname = 'com.' + @dbname
      exec #recursesiteurl @dbname,  @res OUTPUT
   end
GO
-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#recursesiteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #recursesiteurl;
GO
create procedure #recursesiteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)
       
      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #recursesiteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
GO

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_posts ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , bcount int
                            , id int
                            , title nvarchar(250)
                            );
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
               declare @url nvarchar(250)
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               insert into #all_posts 
               select TOP 1 @url
               , Count(Id) AS IdCount
               , PostId 
               , (select title from posts p where Postid = p.id)
               FROM Votes
               WHERE BountyAmount IS NOT NULL 
                 AND VoteTypeId = 8 -- BountyStart
               GROUP BY PostId
               ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;'
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select replace(
       replace(
       replace(site,
         '.StackExchange.com',''),
         '.com',''),
         '.net','') as [site]
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '/q/'
     + cast(id as nvarchar)
     + '|'
     + title as question
     , bcount
from #all_posts
order by bcount desc

drop table #all_posts

drop procedure #recursesiteurl
drop procedure #siteurl
```

When you run this we can confirm the correctness of Nicael's answer:

[image]

Comment: This proves I have guessed :D

Comment: But you're the true SQL magician - I thought the data.se queries only work for one site...

Comment: @nicael it just happens to work but you either need the exec function and build up a sql string (when done wrong you get 150 errors) or a script that generates a single query with databasename.schema.table. Oh, and the timeout is still 120 seconds ....

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to get those stats from all SE sites at once, but per [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/319145/questions-with-the-most-bounties), here on Meta the max amount of bounties is 17, and on Stack Overflow, [it is 13](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/319145/questions-with-the-most-bounties).

<s>I doubt any other site has larger numbers though</s> o.0 [on Tex it is 22](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/319145/questions-with-the-most-bounties).

[On the other relatively big SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), the number varies from 3 to 7 with Physics topping at 11.

Comment: And the SO question with the most was closed as off-topic ...

Comment: @David Well, ok then :) Does it matter?

Comment: Not really, it was just an observation ;) Bounties != Quality

Comment: @David But the fact whether the question is closed or not doesn't always affect the question quality. At some point of time, it was on-topic, now it is not because of scope changing slightly as the time passes, did the quality of the question decrease? I don't think so.

Comment: @DavidPostill The question with 13 bounties on SO was out of desperation from the OP who had a legitimate problem which became off-topic as the site evolved. The question with 10 bounties was repeated advertising from the top answerer before a mod put a stop to it.