# How to search for all questions with bounties across the network?

Tags: feature-request, support, search, bounties

I wanted to search for questions on all SE sites that had a bounty. I am not sure if it is possible, and if it is how can I?

I have seen other questions that show how to find questions on each individual site, but how can I find all of them in one search from the homepage stackexchange.com? If this has been asked already, please let me know.

It has been suggested that the question was already asked (click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269006/what-question-has-had-the-most-bounties-on-it) for the question), but that question only showed how to find those questions on each separate site or some complex way to search. I am hoping to find a way to search for bountied questions easily or for someone to create a way to do this.

Comment: Did you get inspired by [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269006/what-question-has-had-the-most-bounties-on-it)?

Comment: I read that question. I was asking for a simple way to search for all of the questions with a bounty from the main site. The answers in the question you linked to talked about complex ways to search or how to find questions with bounties in each individual SE site.

Comment: But would this really help at all? There are so many types of sites in SE, you probably wouldn't find any questions you could answer very easily... :/

Comment: I wasn't asking for an easy answer. I was asking for an easy way to search for bountied questions

Comment: Is it a puzzle, then? :D

Comment: @nicael Yes it is a mystery.

Comment: Nononono it hasn't been suggested that your question was asked already. Rene just brought another question there because they thought the association with that question made you write this one.

Comment: So clicking [a link](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/386643/sites-with-highest-bounties-cont) to a query is complex?

Comment: @rene what do you mean?

Comment: @rene Your link is broken.

Comment: You seem to suggest that the answers on the question I linked are too complex for your purpose. Those answers try to teach how to fish but in the end it is a link you can follow that runs a pre-baked sql query. If either I or @nicael create such a query, would that answer your question or isn't that what you're looking for in terms of easy.

Comment: @rene I messed up. When I hovered over the link in your first comment, I thought it was another question that I had seen earlier in my search for an answer. I thought that the question you linked to was the question I described, which had more than 2. I am gonna have to ind that again and fix my mistake. Never have seen that question you linked to before just a moment ago.

Comment: I did some experimenting of my own and found out this works: ["This question has an open bounty worth"](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22This+question+has+an+open+bounty+worth%22)

Answer (score 5):

The [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) has two endpoints that we can use to implement this. First we use [`/sites`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=500&filter=!*l7_tSmzy1mF3bw9odQw*8ur&run=true) to get a list of all sites. After that we call [`/questions/featured`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!iCF4LsDYJt6oT_Y1qKBCOv&site=stackoverflow&run=true) to get the per-site featured (bountied) questions.

The following Stack Snippet demonstrates the use of those two end-points and produces a list of all featured questions across all sites. The script does take the API throttle limits into account. When hit (or when a result-set is paged) a link appears at the end of the list that needs to be clicked to continue loading.

```js
(function () {
  var api = {
    url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/',
    endpoint: 'questions/featured',
    params: { 
      site: 'stackoverflow',
      pagesize: 100,
      order: 'desc',
      sort: 'activity',
      Filter: '!iCF4LsDYJt6oT_Y1qKBCOv',
      key: 'JBN9WXWxwrcnAj7WEEytmQ(('
      }
    },
      sites = [],
      siteIndex = -1;
    
    
  function createUrl(ap) {
    var ep = ap.url + ap.endpoint +'?',
     nv = [];
    $.each(ap.params, function (k,v) {
       nv.push(k + '=' + v);
    });
    console.log(ep + nv.join('&'));
    return ep + nv.join('&');
  }
 
  function enableLoad(func) {
    $('#load').show();
    $('#load').one('click', func);
  }
   
  // load a page of featured questions
  function load(page) {
    console.log(sites);
    api.params.page = page;
    api.params.site = sites[siteIndex].sapi;
    $('#load').hide();
    $.get(createUrl(api), function (data) {
      var i, 
          list = $('#fav'),
          next;
      for(i = 0; i < data.items.length; i = i +1) {
          list.append(
            $('<div></div>').append(
              $('<img/>')
                .attr('src',sites[siteIndex].url)
                .attr('title',sites[siteIndex].name),
            $('<a></a>')
              .attr('href', data.items[i].link)
              .attr('title', data.items[i].bounty_amount)
              .html(data.items[i].title)
            ));
      }
      if (data.has_more) {
        next = function () { load(page + 1); };
        if (data.backoff !== undefined) {
          window.setTimeout( function () {
              enableLoad(next);
            }, 
            data.items.backoff * 1000);  
        } else {
            enableLoad(next);
        }
      } else {
        siteIndex = siteIndex + 1;
        if (siteIndex < sites.length) {
          load(1);
        } else {
           $('#load').hide(); 
          }
      }
    });
  }

  // load all sites and setup sites array
  function loadSites() {
   $.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?pagesize=500&filter=!*l7_tSmzy1mF3bw9odQw*8ur&key=JBN9WXWxwrcnAj7WEEytmQ((', function(data) {
        var i;
         for(i=0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
           if (data.items[i].site_type === 'main_site') {
                sites.push({ "name": data.items[i].name,
                             "sapi": data.items[i].api_site_parameter,
                             "url": data.items[i].icon_url
                            });
             }
           }
        sites.sort(function(a,b) { 
          return a.name < b.name?-1: a.name>b.name?1:0; 
        });
        siteIndex = 0;
        
        if (data.backoff !== undefined) {
          window.setTimeout( function () {
              load(1);
            }, 
            data.items.backoff * 1000);  
        } else {
            load(1);
        }
      });
  }
  
  loadSites();
}());
```

```css
#onhold div {
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  }

#load {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center; 
  cursor: pointer
  }

img {
  height: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error" style="display:none">
</div>
<div id="fav">
  
</div>
<div id="load" style="display:none">
 Click to load more ...
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

With "one search from the homepage stackexchange.com", the most closest alternative I find is to search for `"featured questions - "` using the network wide search, powered by Google (<-- which means that the SE magical search operators don't work), **but this starts to output unwanted results  from the pages > 2**.

https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22featured%20questions%20-%20%22

This will show the lists of the featured questions on all the SE sites and you can click on one list.

The other options, like searching for "This question has an open bounty" doesn't work because the google search seems to be cached. The data explorer won't help there because it's updated only every week (though I believe @rene can create one, taking the questions with the bounties set < 8 days ago).

So, I'm not sure there's direct alternative to the per-site [featured lists](/questions/?sort=featured).

Comment: Your search isn't the greatest. I did some experimenting of my own and found out this works: ["This question has an open bounty worth"](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22This+question+has+an+open+bounty+worth%22)

Comment: @AChildofGod *The other options, like searching for "This question has an open bounty" doesn't work because the google search seems to be cached* - look at the results: the 44% of those results would be wrong because of already expired bounties and bounties which were started less than 2 days ago. And also the first is just a meta post about the bounty.

Comment: Remind me what the first is.

Comment: Well, the first result of your search. Or have you lost your comment?