# Which answer has the most bounty points awarded to it?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, statistics, fun

Which answer has had the most bounty points awarded to it? It would obviously have been awarded multiple bounties.

Answer (score 12):

(From slightly adjusting [the query here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269010/145673))

There are currently 25 answers that have been awarded bounties in excess of 1,000 reputation.

Overall it is an answer on the Tex site to [How to extract each pair of two adjacent cells of a table into a separate tight page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209821) (+2050).

The highest on StackOverflow is
[Improve GeSHi syntax highlighting for T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23773356/73226) (+2000).

And on this site [Add escalation system to chat flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116195/145673) (+1700).

Tex also has another 4 answers with +2000 bounties. A list of all 25 is below.

```
+---------------+--------------+----------+
|     site      | BountyAmount |    id    |
+---------------+--------------+----------+
| Tex           |         2050 |   209821 |
| Tex           |         2000 |   102924 |
| Tex           |         2000 |   120860 |
| Tex           |         2000 |   131694 |
| Tex           |         2000 |   149134 |
| StackOverflow |         2000 | 23773356 |
| StackOverflow |         1700 | 21468591 |
| Meta          |         1700 |   116195 |
| StackOverflow |         1500 |  5864000 |
| Tex           |         1500 |   107613 |
| Tex           |         1500 |    80557 |
| Scifi         |         1500 |   105743 |
| Dba           |         1400 |    16386 |
| StackOverflow |         1350 | 13600004 |
| StackOverflow |         1250 | 15890063 |
| StackOverflow |         1150 | 11227902 |
| StackOverflow |         1100 | 24929846 |
| StackOverflow |         1100 | 15703714 |
| Meta          |         1100 |   233596 |
| Gaming        |         1100 |    57802 |
| Meta          |         1050 |    92576 |
| Meta          |         1050 |   196178 |
| Meta          |         1050 |    27846 |
| Meta          |         1050 |   126693 |
| Meta          |         1050 |   243263 |
+---------------+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: [Ahem.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105743/31394) 3750 and counting, not just 1500 any more :-)

Comment: If @JonSkeet staked his entire rep as a bounty on one question, he'd get it all back in upvotes...and more. :-p

Comment: @Randal'Thor 5100!