# How can a user earn more than 2000 rep in a week?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-leagues

I am a bit confused seeing the [first page of reputation earned in a week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2019-12-22?sort=reputationchange&page=1), which is **more than 2000 for the top user?** According to [What is the "daily reputation cap"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63327/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap), when you pass 200 you stop earning for the day. 7 x 200 = 1400 max. Maybe 1500 if it's 200+, meaning you could gain something like 209.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can check the reputation tab on their profile to see where the reputation actually comes from, but in short the daily reputation cap is only for reputation earned from upvotes and suggested edits. It doesn't prevent you from also earning reputation by other means, such as accepted answers or bounties.

Comment: bounties of course i meant to exclude this from my question.

Comment: panoskarajohn - Accepts, also thousands down and thousands up, while maintaining the '200 window' *still* counts as "earning"; otherwise you'd be losing. As for bounties, that you whittled away: This [looks like 4500 awarded on May 6](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105743/110535), and [here's an answer with a Query showing > 2K bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269080/282094). There's a 'handout limit' but no receive limit.

Comment: Also the association bonus

Answer (score 10):

In this case, the reputation league shows the correct amount of reputation gained. However, there is a bug in the functionality involving deleted posts, which are [calculated as if they were not deleted *and* not subject to the daily reputation limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335517/295232). This leads to situations where [several users appear to have gained way more than 2000 reputation in a week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/week/meta/2019-10-06), sometimes even more than their actual reputation:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Easy one: by putting in tremendous amounts of time and energy.

See a user like [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) on Stack Overflow.

Besides writing books and running a successful business place, he writes 10, 20 answers *per* day. Any day. Great answers that is. So he makes 200 reputation from upvotes, and then 90, 180, ... from accepts on many answers. Every day. 2000 rep in 5 days, that would be a normal week for Gordon.

The secret is that the daily reputation cap limit is only about question and answer upvotes. Other "sources of income " simply go on top of it. I think the current record is a person on Stack Overflow who made 1705 in one day by collecting 7 bounties that day (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365912/1531124)).

But as explained: it is possible to make much more than 200 reputation per day. You can do that on scale. But of course, that costs your time.

Answer (score 1):

Accepts aren't counted in rep caps, also bounties, so many reputation can be earned a day, just takes work!

The 200 rep cap is for upvotes only, as mentioned in [The Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from the combination of upvotes, downvotes and suggested edits. But Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to this daily reputation limit.